# Gedit: Search next match ... usability

Tags: shortcut-keys, gedit, search, usability

Searching the next match with gedit makes me crazy.

1. I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
2. The search input box opens
3. I enter *foo*
4. There is a match for *foo*. Nice
5. Up to now everything is sane
6. I want to search the next match (with keyboard, not mouse): How?

For me <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (again) would be intuitive.

But both don't work...

Am I the only one being confused here?

Version: Gedit 3.10.4 (default of Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: I created a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1499671

Answer (score 16):

https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-search.html.en

According to this then up/down arrows work, as do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>.

I agree, it's not all that intuitive if you're used to more powerful editors - I look at gedit as being equivalent to notepad. Useful in an emergency, but not for Real Work[tm] :)

Comment: I'd add that Ctrl-G & Ctrl-Shift-G are usually the `next` and `previous` match respectively in a lot of application. It is somewhat of a default shortcut now. (just like Ctrl+Tab is for switching tabs in apps, and Ctrl+F is for `Find`). Also Ctrl+G are better than the up/down arrows as the later won't work if you change focus from the search box to the actual content of the file.

Answer (score 4):

When you open the search bar in gedit and enter text, this will look like in the example screenshot below.

[image]

All occurrences of the search pattern `is` are highlighted in the text.
Additionally, one occurrence is selected. You can jump with this selection between the occurrences using either the mouse to click on the <kbd>⋀</kbd>/<kbd>⋁</kbd> buttons of the search bar, or also **by using the <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> cursor arrow keys of your keyboard.**

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. May I ask you a question? Do you think the current behaviour is good usability? BTW, I want a mouse-less solution.

Comment: I used to work with editors that jump to the next search result with F3 or SHIFT+F3. It's just a matter of habituation which one you prefer, I think. There are shortcuts, that's the most important thing. Which one exactly is not that relevant. But that's only an opinion, of course. - Btw. don't forget to accept an answer.